# Is it possible to write a c++ client using WinHttp APIs to receive PUSH notification from an HTTP Server?

Tags: c++, http, push-notification, winhttp

I have created a sample chat application using .NET Framework WebAPI project using the reference: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/push-notification-in-web-application-using-web-api-and-pushcontentstream)
[enter link description here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/push-notification-in-web-application-using-web-api-and-pushcontentstream/)

I tried to create an MFC client application to communicate with this server.
For that used WinHttp functions. But while sending request using "WinHttpSendRequest" API, it is waiting for some time (~30seconds) and returns success. The request received at WebAPI chat server without delay  when the "WinHttpSendRequest" API is called. 
Then while calling "WinHttpReceiveResponse" API, it fails with timeout error.

The sample MFC client application can communicate with other servers which can send HTTP response other than content-type: text/event-stream.

So my doubt is, is it possible to create an http client in c++ to subscribe for PUSH notification and receive PUSH notification (content-type: text/event-stream)?
My aim is to create a client in c++ using Windows default libraries.

Please give your valuable advice. Thank you.

Comment: Anything that receives an HTTP PUSH is by definition an HTTP server, not a client, and likewise anything that sends one is a client, not a server.

Answer (score 0):

Use "WinHttpSetTimeouts" API to set receive timeout as infinite (-1). Then "WinHttpSendRequest" API will wait until a response (PUSH notification) is received from server.
After receiving the response, subscribe for the PUSH notification by calling "WinHttpSendRequest" again. That is subscription should be done after receiving each PUSH notification.